# \and in author affiliation list not working as expected

Tags: author, affiliation

I have a latex code to list authors and the corresponding affiliation. authors are separated by \and. as you can see, this works fine in the green rectangle, and a nice dot shows up between the authors. however, I am not able to reproduce the same thing for the second set of authors, the rectangle in red. the code that I'm using, including all packages, follows below

**link for the svjour3.cls class**
https://www.e-publications.org/springer/support/spr-chicago.html

[image: problem]

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}       % onecolumn (second format)
\smartqed  % flush right qed marks, e.g. at end of proof
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fourier} 
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup{compatibility=false}
\sloppy
\usepackage{needspace}
\usepackage{lineno}
\renewcommand\theadalign{bc}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{\Gape[4pt]}
\renewcommand\cellgape{\Gape[4pt]}
\definecolor{SEcyan}{rgb}{0.000, 0.471, 0.682}
\newcommand{\ccyan}[1]{{\color{SEcyan}#1}}
\newcommand{\marco}[1]{\textbf{\ccyan{#1}}}
\newcommand{\comment}[1]{}

\begin{document}

\title{title}

\author{Catarina Garbacz \and Walter T. Maier \and James B. Scoggins \and Thomas D. Economon \and Thierry Magin \and Juan J. Alonso \and Marco Fossati       
}

\institute{Catarina Garbacz \and Marco Fossati \at
Aerospace Centre of Excellence, University of Strathclyde, Glasgow, G1 1XJ, United Kingdom\\
\email{ana.gomes@strath.ac.uk}     \\
\email{marco.fossati@strath.ac.uk}\\\\[-1ex]
Wally T. Maier \and Juan J. Alonso
\at
Stanford University, Stanford, CA 94305, U.S.A.\\\\[-1ex]
James B. Scoggins \at
\'{E}cole Polytechnique, Route de Saclay, 91128 Palaiseau, France\\\\[-1ex]
Thomas D. Economon \at
SU2 Foundation, San Francisco, CA, 94158 USA\\\\[-1ex]
Thierry Magin \at
von Karman Institute for Fluid Dynamics, Rhode-Saint-Genese, 1640, Belgium\\
}
\end{document}
```

any solutions/ workarounds ?

It's been a very annoying small detail. Thank you

Comment: As always on this site please provide a full minimal example others can copy and test as is. I have no idea which package or documentclass implement a syntax like this.

Comment: apologies. I added the complete sample. any suggestions?

Comment: As svjour3 is not a common class, please also provide a link to it.

Comment: Link for the  svjour3 provided in the edited post

Comment: Note that your example is incomplete and does not seem to give the image you provide

Comment: Are you sure that Rhode-Saint-Genèse or Sint-Genesius-Rode spells as you do it in English?

Comment: thanks for the help daleif but I got my solution below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your usage of `\institute` is not fully correct. Please take the following as an example

```
\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}       % onecolumn (second format)


\begin{document}

\title{title}

\author{Catarina Garbacz \and Walter T. Maier \and James B. Scoggins \and Thomas D. Economon \and Thierry Magin \and Juan J. Alonso \and Marco Fossati
}

\institute{%
Catarina Garbacz \and Marco Fossati \at
Aerospace Centre of Excellence, University of Strathclyde, Glasgow, G1 1XJ, United Kingdom
\email{ana.gomes@strath.ac.uk}
\email{marco.fossati@strath.ac.uk}
\and
Wally T. Maier \and Juan J. Alonso
\at
Stanford University, Stanford, CA 94305, U.S.A.
\and 
James B. Scoggins \at
\'{E}cole Polytechnique, Route de Saclay, 91128 Palaiseau, France
\and 
Thomas D. Economon \at
SU2 Foundation, San Francisco, CA, 94158 USA
\and
Thierry Magin \at
von Karman Institute for Fluid Dynamics, Rhode-Saint-Genese, 1640, Belgium
}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks dude, you saved the day!

Comment: @CatarinaGarbacz You're welcome. The right way to say thanks here is to approve the answer. Please do so if it helped you.

Comment: thanks, first time here